# Sending Push Registration from Xamarin.Forms Android to Azure Notification Hubs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub

I cannot send a registration from my Xamarin.Forms Android App to the Notification Hub.
After Calling

```
hub.Register(token, tags)
```

I get the following Android error:

> Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java
>   security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.

The hub is initialized by

```
hub = new NotificationHub(hubname, listconnectionstring, this)
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that error was the fact that I used Azure Germany. It seems that their Hub Endpoint is causing the error.

I changed to Azure Global and the Hub Connection was successful.